# Copying from One Word Document to Another Results in Run-time error 4605

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to copy the text from one word document to replace a specific paragraph in another. The code is below:

```
Sub OpenDoc()
    Dim strFile1 As String
    Dim strFile2 As String
    Dim oDoc1 As Document
    Dim oDoc2 As Document
       
    strFile1 = "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Example Doc1.docm"  
    
    If Dir(strFile1) <> "" Then        
        Set oDoc1 = Documents.Open(strFile1)
        oDoc1.Paragraphs(1).Range.Copy
  
    End If

    strFile2 = "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Example Doc2.docm"    
    If Dir(strFile2) <> "" Then       
        Set oDoc2 = Documents.Open(strFile2)
        oDoc2.Paragraphs(7).Range.PasteAndFormat(wdPasteDefault)
       
    End If
End Sub
```

While both documents are open, the solutions work intermittently: First run it works, but running again might give  Run-time error 4605 This command is not available, and selects         `oDoc2.Paragraphs(7).Range.PasteAndFormat(wdPasteDefault)` as the problematic line. If I reset the code after the error, it might run perfectly. I cannot figure out why it works sometimes and not others.

If I try pasting manually, after getting the error, the result is exactly what should have been copied. So I don't think there is anything wrong with how I copied from the first document.

It also looks like if I close the document which the text is being pasted and then run the code, it works every time. However, the process become a lot slower if I have to wait for the document to open each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without using copy and paste.

```
Sub OpenDoc()
    Dim strFile1 As String
    Dim strFile2 As String
    Dim oDoc1 As Document
    Dim oDoc2 As Document
       
    strFile1 = "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Example Doc1.docm"
    
    If Dir(strFile1) <> "" Then Set oDoc1 = Documents.Open(strFile1)
  
    strFile2 = "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Example Doc2.docm"
    If Dir(strFile2) <> "" Then Set oDoc2 = Documents.Open(strFile2)
    
    If Not oDoc1 Is Nothing Then
        If Not oDoc2 Is Nothing Then
            oDoc2.Paragraphs(7).Range.FormattedText = oDoc1.Paragraphs(1).Range.FormattedText
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```